# How to call a c# method from javascript in window phone 7?

Tags: windows-phone-7, webbrowser-control, swipe-gesture

I want to detect swipe in web browser control in C# using JavaScript. I want to add some JavaScript to my web content and then if swipe occurs, call a method that loads another web content in the same web browser control.

I would like some sample code or any other suggestion to do this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5):

You'll need to use something to detect the swipe in javascript. I've been recommended to use [touch.js](https://gist.github.com/250316) but haven't had a chance to try this yet.

When you detect the swipe you can call out to native code using `window.external.notify()`.

Be sure to set `IsScriptEnabled="True"` on the WebBrowser control and register an handler for the `ScriptNotify` event.
It's this event handler which would load the new content.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, consider that gestures for a webbrowser control have it's own handlers. Now, if you don't need to pan/zoom or the like in the webbrowser control, it's not a problem.

Then you simply set the `IsHitTestEnabled` attribute to false, so that the web-browser no longer receives input. Then you can simply use the `GestureService` from the [Silverlight Toolkit](http://silverlight.codeplex.com) to handle the swipe/flick inputs.

I wrote some code on how to handle this, in another question: [wp7 horizontal swipe selection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7064430/wp7-horizontal-swipe-selection/7064663#7064663)