# How i Scroll web browser control in wp7

Tags: windows-phone-7

i want to swipe webbrowser Control which is on pivot item ,each pivot item 
has a web control .i want to swipe with web browser control . 
but i don't have any idea.but swiping is necessary in my project .is there any method to doing this if yes then please send me sample code for this ..

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to call a c# method from javascript in window phone 7?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7093007/how-to-call-a-c-method-from-javascript-in-window-phone-7)

Comment: @Claus while a related question it doesn't appear to be a duplicate.

Comment: It seems very much as a duplicate to me.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bind if you have some different sections of HTML you want to display in a Pivot. If you are targetting WP7 Mango it might be possible for you to convert your HTML to RTF and then use a RichTextBox instead of a WebBrowser. However if your HTML is fairly complex, this probably isn't going to work for you.

Alternatively you could place your `WebBrowser` in a pivot item with a transparent `Rectangle` above it in the Z-order. Make sure that `Rectangle` swallows any gestures and doesn't pass them through to the WebBrowser control - that way you will be able to swipe left and right on the WebBrowser to get the pivot to move.

Next you can use the `GestureService` on this transparent rectangle to recognize vertical pans/swipes and taps to take you to a full page view of your `WebBrowser` content. In this full page view you would have a fully interactive `WebBrowser` control.

Answer (score 0):

You have an issue with competing gestures. Try setting the WebBrowser control to `IsHitTestVisible` to false. This will mean that you'll be unable to manipulate or scroll the content of the WebBrowser control though.

Comment: But i want to Scroll my browser up and down and when  we flick it right or left it swipe.

Comment: @shanu Your best solution will be to change the design so that you don't use the WebBrowser in a pivot.

Answer (score 0):

shanu: if you still need it, check my recent answer at: [WP7 Pivot control and a WebBrowser control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5417293/wp7-pivot-control-and-a-webbrowser-control/7347448#7347448)
There's a bit of info on how to "hack into" the webbrowser and what to do, to (almost) prevent it from stealing your swipes. If you are insane/masochistic enough to try that approach I described there, then in addition to that eventhandling and other configuration/detection, you will have to drive your pivot manually via relevant pivot.selectedindex++/-- on H-swipes  detected with your handlers (or you can separate blocking and observing with gesture listener, that may sometimes result in the code being a bit cleaner). I also think you will have to be careful with the selectedindex near to the page ranges. I dont know how pivot behaves if you order it to go further than you page count, and I dont know either if it will **animate** correctly, if being on the last page you order it to go "wrap around" and go to page 0 via selectedindex=0. It may get "crazy" and rewind back instead of going forward in a circular fashion.. you will have to experiment with that