# MY web Broswer doesn't support silver light toolkit tap event and flick event

Tags: windows-phone-7

```
       <controls:PivotItem Header="item1">
            <Grid>
                <phone:WebBrowser IsHitTestVisible="False" Source="www.google.com">
                    <toolkit:GestureService.GestureListener>
                        <toolkit:GestureListener Tap="onTap" Flick="GestureListener_Flick" />
                    </toolkit:GestureService.GestureListener>

                </phone:WebBrowser>
            </Grid>
        </controls:PivotItem>
```

the code behind this

```
       private void onTap(object sender, GestureEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("tap");
       // Listbox.index = m.SelectedIndex;
        //  m.SelectedIndex = -1;
      //  App.Navigate(new Uri("/Home.xaml", UriKind.Relative));



    }
    private void GestureListener_Flick(object sender, FlickGestureEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Direction == System.Windows.Controls.Orientation.Horizontal)
        {
            if (e.HorizontalVelocity < 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("right");
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("left");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (e.VerticalVelocity < 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("up");
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("down"); 
            }
        }
    }
```

but it doesn't work ...
thanx in advance..

Answer (score 0):

These events are not supported on the WebBrowser control. The main reason for this is probably that it's hard to distinguish whether the user is interacting with a webpage (scrolling or clicking a link) or whether you would like to capture the events on the control.

Comment: @Shanu you need to put a transparent rectangle on top of your disabled WebBrowser and put the gesture detection there: [see my answer to your previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7093491/how-i-scroll-web-browser-control-in-wp7/7106129#7106129).