# Implement Swipe event on WP8

Tags: windows-phone-8, swipe

I am creating a wp8 application for showing some html files in a browser and the structure is

```
    <Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid Name="PageNavigationMenu">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Button Height="70" Content="P"  Grid.Column="0"  VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Click="btnPrevious_Click" x:Name="btnPrevious" ></Button>
        <Button Height="70"  Content="N"  Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Center"  Click="btnNext_Click" x:Name="btnNext"></Button>
    </Grid>
    <Grid Grid.Row="1" Hold="Grid_Hold">
        <phone:WebBrowser IsScriptEnabled="True" x:Name="mainBrowserControl">

        </phone:WebBrowser>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Now i am using a previous button and next button to change the content in browser . I want to do it using the Swipe Left / Swipe Right on browser . Like if user Swipe left direction , borswer content should be loaded with previous page and Swipe right results to load next page.

So what are the events i have to listen to implement swipe feature

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two possibilities (AFAIK):
You can use XNA TouchPanel (more information about it you can find here: [Working with TouchInput](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff434208.aspx), [Detecting Gestures](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff827740.aspx) and this [blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/nicgrave/archive/2010/07/12/touch-gestures-on-windows-phone-7.aspx)) for this:

```
public MainPage()
{
   InitializeComponent();

   TouchPanel.EnabledGestures = GestureType.Flick;
   myWebbrowser.ManipulationCompleted += myWebbrowser_ManipulationCompleted;
}

private void myWebbrowser_ManipulationCompleted(object sender, System.Windows.Input.ManipulationCompletedEventArgs e)
{
   if (TouchPanel.IsGestureAvailable)
   {
      GestureSample gesture = TouchPanel.ReadGesture();
      switch (gesture.GestureType)
      {
        case GestureType.Flick:
            if (e.FinalVelocities.LinearVelocity.X < 0)
                        LoadNextPage();
            if (e.FinalVelocities.LinearVelocity.X > 0)
                        LoadPreviousPage();
            break;
        default:
            break;
      }
  }
}
```

Or you can use [Silverlight Toolkit](http://silverlight.codeplex.com/releases/view/55034) as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4342558/2681948) or [other here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7064663/2681948).
**EDIT** - small remark
Only watch out, because when you use XNA, you sometimes need to do (for example OnNavigatedTo):

```
FrameworkDispatcher.Update();
```

Otherwise your App will sometimes crash.

Hope this helps.
**EDIT 2** - code example after comment
In case your ManipulationEvent is handeled first (for example by Pivot or Map), I tried to subscribe to `Touch.FrameReported` - as I've tested - it should work:

```
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    TouchPanel.EnabledGestures = GestureType.Flick;
    Touch.FrameReported += Touch_FrameReported;
}

private void Touch_FrameReported(object sender, TouchFrameEventArgs e)
{
   if (TouchPanel.IsGestureAvailable)
   {
      GestureSample gesture = TouchPanel.ReadGesture();
      switch (gesture.GestureType)
      {
         case GestureType.Flick:
             if (gesture.Delta.X > 0)
                  MessageBox.Show("Right");
             if (gesture.Delta.X < 0)
                  MessageBox.Show("Left");
             break;
         default:
             break;
      }
   }
}
```

**NEXT EDIT**  (after next comments) - better implementation and example of disabling up, down gestures:

If you don't want to activate for up (little left)/down (little right), you have to describe conditions yourself. Be aware that there is a very little chance (if any) that user will move his finger only left/right/up/down - so you have to include some margin. There are many solutions for that, you have to try and play with it, the simpliest solutions just compare deltaX and deltaY of gesture:

```
public MainPage()
{
   InitializeComponent();
   TouchPanel.EnabledGestures = GestureType.Flick | GestureType.HorizontalDrag;
   Touch.FrameReported += Touch_FrameReported;
}

TouchPoint firstPoint;
private void Touch_FrameReported(object sender, TouchFrameEventArgs e)
{
   TouchPoint mainTouch = e.GetPrimaryTouchPoint(ContentPanel);

   if (mainTouch.Action == TouchAction.Down) firstPoint = mainTouch;
   else if (mainTouch.Action == TouchAction.Up && TouchPanel.IsGestureAvailable)
   {
       double deltaX = mainTouch.Position.X - firstPoint.Position.X;
       double deltaY = mainTouch.Position.Y - firstPoint.Position.Y;
       if (Math.Abs(deltaX) > 2 * Math.Abs(deltaY))
       {
           if (deltaX < 0) MessageBox.Show("Right.");
           if (deltaX > 0) MessageBox.Show("Left.");
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: How can i produce this effect on emulator?

Comment: @JMat As I've tested it - on emulator it's working when you click (don't hold) on screen (or your webbrowser, I've subscribed to MainPage_Manipulation so works on whole screen) and move your mouse fast from left or rigt. Give it a try.

Comment: I tested it , but not working . Might be i am listening to some other events like DragCompleted etc ( but not able to find reason for it). Can you post the sample project / Complete page code somewhere , so i can run and test

Comment: @JMat It's no problem as I've it already done - second edit. It's almost identical to orginal one.

Comment: Sorry for late reply .Busy with some other part of the app.
I tried to follow the approach , but for me the manipulation completed event was firing only when i swipe left or right on some button controls. If i simply swipe left or right inside page nothing happends, any idea why?

Comment: @JMat Check this example: http://sdrv.ms/LxlLng I assume that you have no problem with invoking this gesture on emulator (quick click with fat movement - I sometimes have troubles). Then can be some resons why it wouldn't work - for example you can have element which handles the gesture first -Pivot, Map. I'll edit my answer to show what you can do in such a case

Comment: @JMat I've edited `second edit` - check if that helped. BTW - probably your webbrowser handles Manipulation Event, the third (second) edit should work.

Comment: Yes the final edit worked for me . Thanks a lot for giving this tip.
One more question in the same context - Is using PIVOT (3 pivot items one for showing current page , one for previous page and one for next page) or using a single grid and change the browser source on swipe .Which is better approach ? In the first case i have to use 3 different web browser controls and in second case just one browser control is enough. Whats ur suggestion

Comment: @JMat Pivot can give in some cases more flexibility as there can be more controls inside PivotItem (so previous page can have different). But you will have to handle such situation as - user looks at page 1,2,3,4 the 4th is current, then goes back to 3 (previous pivot item), and wants to go one more time to previous - 2, but he is already on previous pivot item. What then? I think it depends on your choice at the purpose of the App. And if the answer solved your problem, don't forget to mark it as solution ;)

Comment: Is there any way to prevent this swipe feature to a specifiv page only . Touch.FrameReported += Touch_FrameReported; will fire if we swipe right / left anywhere in application?

Comment: @JMat I;ve not tried that, but surely you can (I think) unsubscribe from event when you perform OnNavigatedFrom at specific page.

Comment: This approach makes one more problem for me . It fire for both Swipe Left , Swipe Right , Swipe Top and Swipe Bottom events . How can we identify the Swipe id Left / Right / Top / Bottom ( Since i dont wnat to listen for Top /Bottom Swipes)

Comment: @JMat It's quite easy - just check if second dimension Y < 20 while X > 20 (for example), if Y > X it means user goes up. I think you can figure out more.

Comment: Sorry i am not been able to get it clearly. Is there any documentation so that i can know more about behind measuring position ? Or can you provide an example. Is 20 is a specific limit in the geometry or can i look for >0 < 0 like it ?

Comment: @JMat See my improvement edit. You have to play with it, it depend on you how you set the margin. You have to fit it to your App, I doubt there is any documentation. Try to move your finger and see in debug how many Times you moved only left/right without any up/down.