# How to implement horizontal swipe control in windows phone 8?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

Kindly help me in this topic, Am developing my first app on windows phone 8 and I have stuck up at this point. I have a UI page, At which in the bottom of the page i want to have a swipe control on those items only( not on the entire page). Kindly help me out in this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: you will need Flick Gesture for this see this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21399514/implement-swipe-event-on-wp8)

Comment: @dhee are you satisfied with the answer? If so please mark as accepted

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I understand it you simply want a list that you can swipe horizontally?

You can insert it using this:

```
<ListBox ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
              <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Your control... />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```