# Catch the event of slip with one finger to the right/left in a Windows Phone application

Tags: events, windows-phone-8, touch

All is in the title. I'm actually developing a kind of image gallery and I would like the user slip with one finger to the right to see the next picture and to the left picture for the previous. Whence my question : Is there a way to capture the event when the user slip his finger on the screen in Windows Phone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `GestureService` in the Silverlight Control [Toolkit](https://silverlight.codeplex.com/releases) for Windows Phone. In your UI element, add the following piece of code.

XAML:

```
<toolkit:GestureService.GestureListener>
<toolkit:GestureListener Flick="OnFlick"/>
</toolkit:GestureService.GestureListener>
```

.cs:

```
private void OnFlick(object sender, FlickGestureEventArgs e)
{
var vm = DataContext as SelectedCatalogViewModel;

if (vm != null)
{
 // User flicked towards left
if (e.HorizontalVelocity < 0)
{
// Load the next image 
LoadNextPage(null);
}

// User flicked towards right
  if (e.HorizontalVelocity > 0)
  {
     // Load the previous image
     LoadPreviousPage();
  }
 }
}
```

Have a look here : [Implement Swipe event on WP8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21399514/)

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks you anonshankar. It's exactly what I was looking for.